# having trouble during initial build for project "gameoflife" when following "jenkins the definitive guide" by john ferguson

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm a beginner trying to learn Jenkins by following "Jenkins the definitive guide" by John Ferguson. I have downloaded the sample project "gameoflife" from github and have set the initial configuration for Maven, Git and Java jdk. However, when I first start the build process, the project is supposed to pass. But I keep getting build failure message. Because I'm new to Jenkins, I am not sure what I did wrong and how to fix it.

I have attached a copy of the failure message below.

```
Started by an SCM change
Building in workspace C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\workspace\gameoflife-default
Installing C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\jdk.exe
[hudson.model.JDK] $ C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\jdk.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature" REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR=C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK /L C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\tools\install5268142390914952134log
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\jdk.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK"): CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:240)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:212)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:388)
    at hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.install(JDKInstaller.java:271)
    at hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.performInstallation(JDKInstaller.java:144)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:68)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at hudson.model.JDK.forNode(JDK.java:144)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.getEnvironment(AbstractProject.java:357)
    at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2232)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:922)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1090)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
Archiving artifacts
ERROR: Failed to archive artifacts: **/target/*.jar
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete 'C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK'. Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:257)
    at hudson.FilePath.deleteRecursive(FilePath.java:1231)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$1000(FilePath.java:195)
    at hudson.FilePath$14.invoke(FilePath.java:1201)
    at hudson.FilePath$14.invoke(FilePath.java:1198)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1018)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:996)
    at hudson.FilePath.deleteRecursive(FilePath.java:1198)
    at hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.performInstallation(JDKInstaller.java:133)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:68)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at hudson.model.JDK.forNode(JDK.java:144)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.getEnvironment(AbstractProject.java:357)
    at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2232)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:922)
    at hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver.perform(ArtifactArchiver.java:234)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteFile(Util.java:296)
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:252)
    ... 26 more
Recording test results
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ aborted due to exception: 
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete 'C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK'. Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:257)
    at hudson.FilePath.deleteRecursive(FilePath.java:1231)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$1000(FilePath.java:195)
    at hudson.FilePath$14.invoke(FilePath.java:1201)
    at hudson.FilePath$14.invoke(FilePath.java:1198)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1018)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:996)
    at hudson.FilePath.deleteRecursive(FilePath.java:1198)
    at hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.performInstallation(JDKInstaller.java:133)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:68)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at hudson.model.JDK.forNode(JDK.java:144)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.getEnvironment(AbstractProject.java:357)
    at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2232)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:922)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.perform(JUnitResultArchiver.java:146)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteFile(Util.java:296)
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:252)
    ... 26 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: which Jenkins version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest jenkins, 2.7.4.war

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant error message is

```
Cannot run program "C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\jdk.exe" 
(in directory "C:\Users\Justin\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK"): 
CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, 
The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
```

The call stack involves

```
hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.install
```

Try and check the configuration of your Jenkins, and check if there is an ["Install automatically" selected in either your job or in Jenkins "Configure System" main settings section](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jenkins-the-definitive/9781449311155/ch04s05.html).

[image: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jenkins-the-definitive/9781449311155/httpatomoreillycomsourceoreillyimages864759.png]

Make sure you *unselect* that option, and reference the path of a jdk already installed (before following [Ferguson's example](https://books.google.fr/books?id=4bjDCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA337&lpg=PA337&dq=jenkins%20ferguson%20%22gameoflife%22&source=bl&ots=FQjptAPm4W&sig=QwxSdg5NMfJTAqJvybeT57aEyd4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw_uDiv4_PAhXKWhoKHSV2B04Q6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=jenkins%20ferguson%20%22gameoflife%22&f=false)).

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful suggestion! You seem to be quite good at jenkins, do you mind if I ask you what is the best learning path I should take to learn jenkins? and continous integration in general? Thanks again for your help! really appreciate it!

Comment: btw i will give out the bounty points as soon as SO allows me, which is in 10 hours time

Comment: @TonyStark Thank you. I am in charge of a Jenkins instance in my current mission, so it helps a lot. I generally learn those tools at work (and by answering question here on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a6309%20%5bjenkins%5d )

Comment: Dude ... You save my week :p